Running jenkins slaves on a few data centers

Jenkins setup:
Jenkins: 2.452.1
OS: Linux - 6.5.0-26-generic
Java: 17.0.11 - Eclipse Adoptium (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
---
ansicolor:1.0.4
antisamy-markup-formatter:162.v0e6ec0fcfcf6
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.14-208.v438351942757
asm-api:9.7-33.v4d23ef79fcc8
authentication-tokens:1.113.v81215a_241826
bootstrap5-api:5.3.3-1
bouncycastle-api:2.30.1.78.1-233.vfdcdeb_0a_08a_a_
branch-api:2.1169.va_f810c56e895
build-blocker-plugin:1.7.9
build-timeout:1.32
build-token-root:151.va_e52fe3215fc
caffeine-api:3.1.8-133.v17b_1ff2e0599
checks-api:2.2.0
cloudbees-folder:6.928.v7c780211d66e
command-launcher:107.v773860566e2e
commons-lang3-api:3.14.0-76.vda_5591261cfe
commons-text-api:1.11.0-109.vfe16c66636eb_
configuration-as-code:1810.v9b_c30a_249a_4c
credentials:1337.v60b_d7b_c7b_c9f
credentials-binding:677.vdc9d38cb_254d
dark-theme:439.vdef09f81f85e
display-url-api:2.204.vf6fddd8a_8b_e9
durable-task:555.v6802fe0f0b_82
echarts-api:5.5.0-1
eddsa-api:0.3.0-4.v84c6f0f4969e
email-ext:2.105
envinject:2.908.v66a_774b_31d93
envinject-api:1.199.v3ce31253ed13
extra-columns:1.26
font-awesome-api:6.5.2-1
git:5.2.2
git-client:4.7.0
gitlab-plugin:1.8.1
google-login:109.v022b_cf87b_e5b_
gson-api:2.11.0-41.v019fcf6125dc
hashicorp-vault-plugin:368.v48134f694db_f
instance-identity:185.v303dc7c645f9
ionicons-api:74.v93d5eb_813d5f
jackson2-api:2.17.0-379.v02de8ec9f64c
jakarta-activation-api:2.1.3-1
jakarta-mail-api:2.1.3-1
javax-activation-api:1.2.0-7
javax-mail-api:1.6.2-10
jaxb:2.3.9-1
jdk-tool:73.vddf737284550
jersey2-api:2.42-147.va_28a_44603b_d5
job-dsl:1.87
jobConfigHistory:1229.v3039470161a_d
joda-time-api:2.12.7-29.v5a_b_e3a_82269a_
jquery3-api:3.7.1-2
json-api:20240303-41.v94e11e6de726
json-path-api:2.9.0-58.v62e3e85b_a_655
junit:1265.v65b_14fa_f12f0
kubernetes:4244.v4fb_b_00994a_90
kubernetes-client-api:6.10.0-240.v57880ce8b_0b_2
kubernetes-credentials:174.va_36e093562d9
ldap:725.v3cb_b_711b_1a_ef
mailer:472.vf7c289a_4b_420
matrix-auth:3.2.2
matrix-project:832.va_66e270d2946
metrics:4.2.21-451.vd51df8df52ec
mina-sshd-api-common:2.12.1-113.v4d3ea_5eb_7f72
mina-sshd-api-core:2.12.1-113.v4d3ea_5eb_7f72
naginator:1.449.ve19751d70eb_0
okhttp-api:4.11.0-172.vda_da_1feeb_c6e
pam-auth:1.11
pipeline-build-step:540.vb_e8849e1a_b_d8
pipeline-graph-analysis:216.vfd8b_ece330ca_
pipeline-groovy-lib:710.v4b_94b_077a_808
pipeline-input-step:495.ve9c153f6067b_
pipeline-milestone-step:119.vdfdc43fc3b_9a_
pipeline-model-api:2.2198.v41dd8ef6dd56
pipeline-model-definition:2.2198.v41dd8ef6dd56
pipeline-model-extensions:2.2198.v41dd8ef6dd56
pipeline-rest-api:2.34
pipeline-stage-step:312.v8cd10304c27a_
pipeline-stage-tags-metadata:2.2198.v41dd8ef6dd56
plain-credentials:182.v468b_97b_9dcb_8
plugin-util-api:4.1.0
prism-api:1.29.0-15
prometheus:2.5.3
resource-disposer:0.23
role-strategy:727.vd344b_eec783d
scm-api:690.vfc8b_54395023
script-security:1341.va_2819b_414686
simple-theme-plugin:176.v39740c03a_a_f5
slack:722.vd07f1ea_7ff40
snakeyaml-api:2.2-111.vc6598e30cc65
ssh-agent:367.vf9076cd4ee21
ssh-credentials:337.v395d2403ccd4
sshd:3.330.vc866a_8389b_58
startup-trigger-plugin:2.9.4
structs:337.v1b_04ea_4df7c8
theme-manager:262.vc57ee4a_eda_5d
timestamper:1.27
token-macro:400.v35420b_922dcb_
trilead-api:2.147.vb_73cc728a_32e
variant:60.v7290fc0eb_b_cd
workflow-aggregator:596.v8c21c963d92d
workflow-api:1316.v33eb_726c50b_a_
workflow-basic-steps:1058.vcb_fc1e3a_21a_9
workflow-cps:3894.3896.vca_2c931e7935
workflow-durable-task-step:1353.v1891a_b_01da_18
workflow-job:1400.v7fd111b_ec82f
workflow-multibranch:783.va_6eb_ef636fb_d
workflow-scm-step:427.v4ca_6512e7df1
workflow-step-api:657.v03b_e8115821b_
workflow-support:907.v6713a_ed8a_573
ws-cleanup:0.46

Hey,
I'm working on Jenkins in Kubernetes, I have heavy workloads that are running on a few datacenters: AMS, SIN and PHX.
So far I was configuring jenkins in docker on VMs on each datacenter, but now since I'm migrating it to Kubernetes I'm wondering if it's possible to use one jenkins master and schedule a slaves on worker nodes that are on different data centers.
My main concern is about latency between jenkins master and jenkins slave, but maybe it does not leverage on the speed of processing of the job on worker nodes on different data centers?
What can be downsides of this configuration if it's at least doable?

I would change Jenkins by GitOps approach. perhaps fluxcd. it will watch on a repo, and pull rather than ssh and make changes. it will be more secure and less latency. you can customise the manifests with kustomize depending on each datacentre.

This is a perfectly normal setup for Jenkins to be on a different network than agents and the latency doesn't affect how fast or slow jobs run. You just need to ensure network connectivity. And be ready for some network transfer charges, if your agents are in different regions. In my experience logs are small, artifacts are big.
